# Лагает программа из-за частой прорисовки

Tags: java

Я решил создать что-то вроде программы paint (Работаю в аплете) есть 2 Array list (X и Y), добавил к аплету MouseListener и реализовал метод mouseDragged:

```
public void moseDragged(MouseEvent mouse){
    X.add(mouse.getX());
    Y.add(mouse.getY());
    repaint();
}
```

А вот метод paint():

```
private final int SIZE = 10;

public void paint(Graphics g){
    for(int d = 0; d < X.size(); d++)
        g.drawOval(X.get(d) - SIZE, Y.get(d) - SIZE, SIZE * 2, SIZE * 2);
    }
}
```

Но при таком подходе из-за частой перерисовки программа лагает.
Как исправить эти лаги? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может надо спросить, поддерживает ли апплет форму крысы? Програмная крыса всегда будет лагать, кроме случая использования 3D-акселератора.

Comment: Возможно помогут ссылки http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071543/move-image-with-mouse-cursor-in-java-applet, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html

Comment: А зачем такой длинный след крысы? Она ж не попадёт в книгу рекордов, может вам ограничить длинну следа (массив X и Y)?

Comment: А в чем заключается лаг? Если при быстром перемещении мыши растет расстояние между точками, то это нормально, события мыши приходят с определенной частотой, и надо вместо точек [линии рисовать](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32173243/5661663). Если у вас очень много точек, и цикл долго выполняется, то можно вместо списка точек завести `BufferedImage`, рисовать новые точки в нем, а в `paint` делать `g.drawImage`.